# Is every minimal set of generators for a homogeneous ideal composed by homogeneous elements?

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings

An ideal $\mathfrak a$ of a graded ring $A$ is said to be homogeneous if I can find a set of homogeneous generators for $\mathfrak  a$. Is it true that **every** minimal set of generators for a homogeneous ideal $\mathfrak a$ is composed by homogeneous elements?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you stated the problem, I believe the answer is no. Suppose you have an ideal minimally generated by an element $a$ of weight $2$ and an element $b$ of weight $3$. Then it is also minimally generated by $a+ b$ and $b$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider the following homogenous ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ :

$$ I = (x^2+y^2+z^2, xyz, z^5).$$

This is also equal to $ I = (x^2+y^2+z^2, xyz+z^5, xyz- z^5).$

Comment: What if we enforce that $I$ is homogeneous and radical, must every minimal set of generators be homogeneous?

Comment: @doremifasolatido I would recommend asking a new question for that.