# Is there a non-homogeneous ideal whose radical is homogeneous?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, examples-counterexamples

Let $I$ be an ideal, and let $\sqrt{I}$ denote its radical (intersection of all primes containing $I$).

One has that [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238152/is-the-radical-of-a-homogeneous-ideal-of-a-graded-ring-homogeneous)[(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125907/the-radical-of-a-monomial-ideal-is-also-monomial): $I$ homogeneous $\implies $ $\sqrt{I}$ is homogeneous.

> **Question:** Does one also have that: $\sqrt{I}$ homogeneous $\implies$ $I$ is homogeneous?
>
> I.e., can anyone find a counterexample of a non-homogeneous ideal (in any graded ring) whose radical is homogeneous? (That would prove the negation of the contrapositive.)

**Attempt:** Given an ideal $J$, denote by $\mathfrak{h}(J)$ the "homogenization" of $J$, i.e. the ideal generated by the set of all homogeneous elements of $J$. In particular, $J$ is homogeneous $\iff J = \mathfrak{h}(J)$.

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/154050/327486), $\sqrt{\mathfrak{h}(I)} = \mathfrak{h}(\sqrt{I})$ always. If we assume that $\sqrt{I}$ is homogeneous, then as noted above, $\sqrt{I} = \mathfrak{h}(\sqrt{I})$, so in particular: $\sqrt{\mathfrak{h}(I)} = \sqrt{I}$.

So if $\sqrt{I}$ is homogeneous, then we can conclude that $\mathfrak{h}(I)$ and $I$ have the same radical -- however, this is not enough to conclude in general that $I$ and $\sqrt{I}$ are equal, from which it would follow, since $\sqrt{I}$ is homogeneous, that $I$ is homogeneous.

Not being able to go any further than this, and being able to think of non-equal non-radical ideals with the same radical (e.g. $\langle x^2 \rangle$ and $\langle x^3 \rangle$), I suspect that there is a counterexample.

**Motivation:** Since the product of homogeneous elements are again homogeneous, (at least for Noetherian rings) it is fairly easy to use their sets of generators ([consisting only of homogeneous elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106161/an-ideal-is-homogeneous-if-and-only-if-it-can-be-generated-by-homogeneous-elemen)) to argue that the product of homogeneous ideals is again homogeneous. ([Note](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793118/is-every-minimal-set-of-generators-for-a-homogeneous-ideal-composed-by-homogeneo))

I could find [only one proof](http://book.mathreference.com/gradr#hid) for the fact that the intersection of two homogeneous ideals is again homogeneous. However, if it were the case that $\sqrt{I}$ is homogeneous $\implies$ $I$ is homogeneous, then we could use the fact that the product of homogeneous ideals is homogeneous, and the relationship $\sqrt{IJ} = \sqrt{I \cap J} = \sqrt{I} \cap \sqrt{J}$, to prove the result for all homogeneous ideals, not just radical ones.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take $R=k[x,y]$, polynomial ring in two variables with the usual grading and let $I=(x+y^2, y^3)$. Then $I$ is not homogeneous, but $\sqrt{I}=(x,y)$ is.